# Android: Turn screen on and off without locking

Tags: android, screen

I need to turn the screen off and on like when you are doing a call and holding the phone to your ear. The screen then turns off but it isn't locked or anything, it's just black.

What is the best way to do that? I don't want to show a black fullscreen activity if there is another solution...:)

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods for doing that,

```
    PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

// method 1
manager.goToSleep(int amountOfTime);

// method 2
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Your Tag");
wl.acquire();// It will swith off
wl.release(); // And swith on
```

also add this permission,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work as I want it to. I can't test the first one because it needs DEVICE_POWER permission which gives me the error Permission only granted for system apps. And the second one only dims the display a bit but not entirely.