# Turn screen on programmatically without using WAKE_LOCK permission

Tags: android, screen, android-wake-lock, android-powermanager

is there a way to turn on the screen when device is locked. i am listening for proximity sensor events to turn on the screen, but by acquiring wake lock which needs WAKE_LOCK permission.

Is there any alternative. Gravity app in playstore does this without WAKE_LOCK permission. Any hint?

Comment: why not to add WAKE_LOCK permission?

Comment: users are skeptical about this.. they fear battery loss and tend to not install the app

Comment: dont think that its possible..

Comment: check "gravity" app in playstore. It is possible. They don't use any permission. Still they are able to ON the screen based on events triggered using sensor data.

Comment: please post link to the app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Turn screen on and off without locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344359/android-turn-screen-on-and-off-without-locking)